# archive contents of a reviewboard server as read-only

Tags: linux, backup, repository

My team was using an Ubuntu box to host an instance of [Reviewboard](https://www.reviewboard.org/) 2.5.2 that we used for a few years before migrating to a Bitbucket service in the cloud. The machine was maintained by my predecessor who has long-since left the company.

Edit: to clarify, the new service is not Reviewboard, but Bitbucket, and it's hosted on an internal cloud service.

Now that we have a service elsewhere that we don't need to maintain, we want to take this old server offline permanently, but would like to preserve the contents site itself -- that is all of the reviews -- for posterity.

I'd rather not just spin up another Reviewboard instance and I'd also rather not be in the business of maintaining a physical web server -- the idea is that I'd put this in our company cloud.

Now I've done a dump of the json-formatted data via RBTool, however this isn't really useful to me in its current form. Edit: it's not useful because I was hoping for an off-the-shelf way to dump the website in static form.

What I ultimately want is to have these old, archived reviews be searchable and for all the links to work more or less as expected for the sake of convenience.

Has anyone had luck doing something like this?

Comment: Could you add more details? What platform, e.g. azure, gcp. What version of reviewboard has been deployed in the cloud? What is your current migration plan and why? `Now I've done a dump of the json-formatted data via RBTool, however this isn't really useful to me in its current form.` Why is it not useful?

Comment: Maybe just scraping the site as static HTML would be an option ?

Comment: @030: Updated.

The new service is Bitbucket. Sorry for the lack of clarity. We're not planning on using Reviewboard again because an existing CI system that we are now using integrates very well with Bitbucket. It's on an internal cloud service. To clarify, we are **not** spinning up a new Reviewboard instance and have no plans to do so.

The json-formatted data isn't immediately useful simply because I'd rather not have to generate a new website from that.

Comment: @Tensibai:

I thought about it, but was wondering if there was an existing method to do it that wouldn't require me to spend time writing a scraper.

Comment: Don't write a scraper!  `wget` can do it.  http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/downloading-entire-web-site-wget

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I ultimately want is to have these old, archived reviews be
>   searchable and for all the links to work more or less as expected for
>   the sake of convenience.

As already indicated in one of the comments, [wget](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19695143/2777965) could be used to retrieve the content:

```
wget -r --no-parent devops.com
```

will create a devops.com folder and put all files in this directory.